# How to fix my github workflow action so it works on pull requests again?

Tags: github-actions

My workflow file looks like this:

```
on:

  push:
    branches:
      - master 
    paths: 
      - "src/*"
      
  pull_request:
    branches: 
      - master
    paths: 
      - "src/*"
```

At some point i added the `paths: "src/*"` and it simply won't trigger (anymore)?

I tried different things such as the filter on branches/paths, but it's like github actions cannot do PR merge checks? I've set them up with other CI platforms just fine, but i can't get it working with github actions. I have read in some article that PR checks will not work if there is a merge conflict, but that is not the case here either

Comment: Is your PR still opened? Because as it is, the PR event is only triggered on the initial PR, not on subsequent pushes events to the branch that has PR.

Comment: Ohhhh. So specifying types whitelists events and the default even is opened. Now that explains it

Comment: @GuiFalourd Add your answer if you want some rep. I am not the only one running into this issue :)

Answer (score 2):

It might be because your PR is still opened.

As your workflow is implemented:

- The `PR event` is only triggered on **the initial PR**.
- The workflow is not triggered on subsequent `pushes events` to the branch that has PR (and **is not** *master*).